# Polygon pour on internal signal layer ALTIUM

Tags: pcb, altium, copper, copper-pour, polygon

I am working on a six layer PCB, the layers are Top layer, layer 1...layer4, Bottom layer. I am trying to create a polygon pour on any internal layers (for example layer 1). However when I try to pour it, I am not able to do so, Altium simply shows the outline of the polygon but does not fill it. Anyone know what I am missing? As a side note, All my polygon pours on Top and Bottom layers work perfectly fine.

I am using Pour Over all same net objects as the fill mode.

**EDIT:**

In Altium, I am unable to pour polygons on any internal layers (they do not fill), while polygons on the top and bottom layers fill just fine. This is what I get when I try to pour on any internal layer (layer isolation is enabled)
[image]

As you can see only the border is created.

Here are the settings I am using for reference as well.
[image]

If anyone knows the relevant setting to allow me to fill the polygon I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you assigned a net name to the pour?

Comment: Yes It has been assigned, does not change anything however.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the settings window for the polygon:

```
Remove Islands Less Than in Area
```

Your polygon is almost certainly smaller than 2500 sq mil, so it isn't being poured. You can either reduce this number or uncheck the box. Repour and it should be filled.

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

With the layer selected double click on polygon pour, click on the graphical tab and then make sure fill mode is on solid.

Second thing:

Press L then change the view mode to standard 2D (or this can be done if you have the toolbar enabled)

Comment: The fill mode is Solid(copper region) the option Pour over same net polygons is selected, and the correct net is assigned. Standard 2D view mode is selected. Still does not fill properly. Could it be anything else?